# Issues importing Windows registry that was just exported from regedit

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-server-2012-r2, regedit

Running regedit as admin in Windows Server 2012 R2, I create a registry export, then try to import this exact same reg file that I just exported, and I get the following message:

```
Cannot import *****.reg not all data was successfully written to the registry some keys are open by the system or other processes or you have insufficient privileges to perform this operation
```

Any suggestions? Before I make changes to the registry I want to make sure I have a backup that can actually be restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be keys where even the Administrator has no permission. For example, neither the Registry entry for Dektop Background, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Display`, nor its subkeys and values, can be modified directly because the owner is **TrustedInstaller**.

- Open *Regedit* to 'Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Display' by copying the key and pasting into the location bar.

[image: DesktopBackground Reg Key]

- Try to modify a value, e.g. change `Position` from *Bottom* to *Left*.
- An error message is displayed.

[image: Error editing value]

- Right-click on the Key `Display` and click *Permissions...*
- Click the *Advanced* button.

[image: Trusted Installer]

Note that the Owner of the key is *TrustedInstaller*. On an individual basis, it is trivial to take ownership of that key and change permissions so that *Administrator* (or a user) can modify the key in *Regedit* **or load a .REG file for that key**. However, if there are many such keys (e.g. you've exported an entire hive), then [you'll need to run *Regedit* as user *TrustedInstaller*.](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-trustedinstaller-locked-registry-keys-files/) There are applications such as [*PowerRun*](https://www.sordum.org/downloads/?power-run) that enable you to run the CMD prompt or *Regedit* as *TrustedInastaller*, **but double-check any download before using it.** Another application for that purpose was flagged by *many* AV engines at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload).

Note also that with great power comes great responsibility. It is possible to mangle the Registry sufficiently to require reinstalling Windows. Regrettably, I must admit to learning this from experience. Image your entire drive before making major experiments.